# nextSibling difference between IE and FF?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, compatibility, raphael

I just wrote a javascript code for layering in raphaeljs it works perfectly on FF.
But it doesn't on IE. The problem is IE returns `null` for `nextSibling` for any object.

How does one use it correctly, or is there a `nextElementSibling` call in IE?

Here is the code fragment I used to change the order of objects:

```
n = items[selected_item_id].nextSibling.id;
if (n != '') {
  items[selected_item_id].insertAfter(items[n]);
}
```

---

```
<div id="consarea">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100%">
<desc>Created with RaphaÃ«l</desc>
<defs/>
<rect x="188" y="100" width="200" height="200" r="10" rx="10" ry="10" fill="#ee8515" stroke="none" style="opacity: 1;" opacity="1"/>
<rect x="253" y="158" width="50" height="50" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#0080ff" stroke="none" style="opacity: 1;" opacity="1" id="0"/>
<rect x="230" y="140" width="50" height="50" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#c03022" stroke="none" style="opacity: 1;" opacity="1" id="1"/></svg>
```

here it is above. the piece of the html im working on

Comment: For which object do you want to get the next sibling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the following function. It is a cross browser code snippet for next sibling.

```
    function getNextElementSibling(CurrentElement) {
    if (CurrentElement.nextElementSibling) {
        return CurrentElement.nextElementSibling
    } else {
        do {
            CurrentElement = CurrentElement.nextSibling;
        } while (CurrentElement && CurrentElement.nodeType !== 1);
        return CurrentElement;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the nextElementSibling property is only supported in IE9 and not in previous versions of IE (you can check it [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_traversal.html) .

if you want you can get the next sibling using JQuery as follows:

```
var sibling = $('#' + selected_item_id).next();
alert(sibling.attr('id'));
```

Comment: i guess it's because jquery also uses same function to get next element deep down in its code :(

Comment: @Ahmet No, jQuery's next() method works in IE (obviously). The above code is OK, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: <rvml:shape class="rvml" id="2" style="width: 1000px; height: 1000px;" coordsize="1000,1000" path=" m2710,1070 l3210,1070,3210,3070,2710,3070 xe" jQuery1294004891854="38" strokecolor="black" stroked="f" fillcolor="#0080ff" filled="t">

here is an example object im working with
Raphael Object...

Comment: yes it works with other elements but doesnt with these rvml elements which are created with Raphaeljs
there is no problem on selector part of jquery command it gets their style etc. but not the next() call :/