# IE 8 nextSibling Property behaving weirdly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, internet-explorer-8

I am using following markup code in my project.

```
<td>   
 <A style="FONT-SIZE: small" id=MainContent_RefDataMgr_GridRegion_lblRegionName_8 title="Click to select row" onclick=javascript:OnRowClick(this); href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$RefDataMgr$GridRegion$ctl10$lblRegionName','')">test </A>
    <INPUT id=MainContent_RefDataMgr_GridRegion_hdnRegionId_8 value=82 type=hidden name=ctl00$MainContent$RefDataMgr$GridRegion$ctl10$hdnRegionId> 
</td>




 function OnRowClick(objRow) {          
        var hdnSelectdGridRowRegionId =   document.getElementById('<%=hdnGridRowSelectedRegionId.ClientID%>');           
            hdnSelectdGridRowRegionId.value = objRow.nextSibling.nextSibling.value;            

    }
```

So if my Anchor element contains any extra space in his text (test   ) then `objRow.nextSibling.nextSibling.value` is not working , i have to use `objRow.nextSibling.value` but In chrome it's working fine even if text contains any extra space or not.

Please let me know what could the region for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use jQuery instead for cross-browser support $(objRow).next().val();

Comment: @frosdqy thanks for your response. currently i am using jquery instead of it, but i wanted to know reason for that, because html and dom is same in both browsers then why i have to use two level of siblings.

Answer (score 0):

In IE8 the `.nextSibling` (correctly, IMHO) refers to the *text node* that is next to the `<a>`.

However, text nodes don't have a `value`.

You want `.nextElementSibling`.

Comment: Thanks for your response, nextElementSibling is not available in IE8. it is available in Ie9 onwards.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6548748/portability-of-nextelementsibling-nextsibling

Comment: There is a polyfill for that http://compatibility.shwups-cms.ch/en/polyfills/?&id=81